# Python Newspaper library results are inconsistent?

Tags: python, python-newspaper

I'm using Anaconda3, installed newspaper. Seems simple enough, but the results are inconsistent.

http://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
import newspaper
cnn_paper = newspaper.build('http://www.cnn.com')
for article in cnn_paper.articles:
    print(article.url)
print(cnn_paper.size())
```

This simple piece of code sometimes returns all results, other times it returns no result.

Anyone used this library or know a better library to scrape news websites? I prefer not to have to write a parser myself, but if it comes down to it, what should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Found the FIx

https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/issues/243

```
cnn_paper = newspaper.build('http://cnn.com', memoize_articles=False)
```